# Antlr4 lexer predicate needed?

Tags: parsing, newline, antlr4, lexer, regex-lookarounds

I try to parse this piece of text

```
:20: test :254:
aapje
:21: rest
...
```

`:20:` and `:21:` are special tags, because they start the line. `:254:` should be 'normal' text, as it does not start on a newline.

I would like the result to be

```
(20, 'test :254:  \naapje') 
(21, 'rest')
```

Lines are terminated using either `\r\n` or '\n'

I started out trying to ignore the whitespace, but then I match the ':254:' tag as well. So I have to create something that uses the whitespace information.

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
lexer grammar MT9740_lexer;

InTagNewLine :  '\r\n' ~':'; 
ReadNewLine  :'\r\n' ;
```

But the first would consume the `:` How can I still generate these tokens? Or is there a smarted approach?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you're looking for some lexer rules that match the start of a line. This lexer rule should tokenize your :20: or :21: appearing at the start of a line only

```
SOL   :   {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}?  ':' [0-9]+ ':'    ;
```

Your parser rules can then look for this SOL token before parsing the rest of the line.